# nginx make node-red Lost connection to server but deploy works

Tags: nginx, node-red

Greetings I am configuring a node-red server and after apply Nginx redirect I got the following issue.

[image: Image of node-red trying to reconnect and still deploying]

After Using Nginx to redrect subdomain node-red.domain.com to localhost:1880

Nginx redirect config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name sub1.domain.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass "https://127.0.0.1:8080";
        }
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name sub2.domain.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass "https://127.0.0.1:8080";
        }
}
```

Please anyone can help me on that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to enable WebSocket proxying to allow the editor to connect back to the runtime.

To do that you need to add some additional options to your `location` configs:

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass "https://127.0.0.1:8080";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
```

For more information about NGINX and WebSockets, refer to the documentation [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/).

Answer (score 2):

The same works in Synology NAS:

Here under 
Application Portal => Create a reverse Proxy for http://*:1880 or https://*1880

And add in the register Customer Header: Create WebSocket

This will create the following two settings:
Upgrade $http_upgrade;
Connection "upgrade";

And voila no connection lost from inside of the LAN and also from outside.

Comment: Does not look like a relevant answer at all.

Comment: It's absolutely relevant, although a particular case where the docker container is hosted on a Synology NAS. Still useful for some of us.

Comment: Looks like he is solving the same issue but with a proxy other than NginX. While not useful to NginX might be helpful to someone else. Thanks for contributing to the community.